# Android Httppost strange behaviour

Tags: android, mysql, http, connection

I have an Android App example I am trying to include into my App. This example shows how to connect to a MySql database and read the information stored into it (through a php file). If I use the example everything works, but if I include the Java files into my App it does not connect to the DB (I always got "Connection fail"). This is the piece of code:

```
public class DbselectActivity extends Activity {    
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.volantinoweb.it/prova/selectall.php");
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
          HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
          is = entity.getContent();
        }
            catch(Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            //convert response to string
            try {
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          String line = null;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input Reading pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
          is.close();
          result=sb.toString();
        }
            catch(Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

...
...
...

Comment: No one can help me ?

Comment: I found the solution... not using AsyncTask I had to use a minSDKversion lower than 8... I used 19